# MongoDB - Root and dbOwner are not authorized to run update command

Tags: r, mongodb, authentication

In the end I want to work with R+MongoDB. Therefor I set up MongoDB on Linux and did the following:

- run mongo command on shell
- use admin db
- add root user
- auth as root: db.auth("root","PASSWORD")
- This are the root users permissions

  ```
  {
  "_id" : "admin.root",
  "user" : "root",
  "db" : "admin",
  "roles" : [
      {
          "role" : "dbOwner",
          "db" : "admin"
      },
      {
          "role" : "readWrite",
          "db" : "admin"
      },
      {
          "role" : "root",
          "db" : "admin"
      }
  ]}
  ```

Run commands in order to make authentification between R und Mongo work

```
> var schema = db.system.version.findOne({"_id" : "authSchema"})
> schema.currentVersion = 3
3
> db.system.version.save(schema)
```

Get the following result

```
WriteResult({
"writeError" : {
    "code" : 13,
    "errmsg" : "not authorized on admin to execute command { update: \"system.version\", updates: [ { q: { _id: \"authSchema\" }, u: { _id: \"authSchema\", currentVersion: 3 }, multi: false, upsert: true } ], ordered: true }"
}})
```

Root and dbOwner is not allowed to execute updates? What am I missing? o.0

Answer (score 10):

I ran into the same problem myself. It turned out I needed the "__system" role.

```
db.grantRolesToUser ( "root", [ { role: "__system", db: "admin" } ] )
```

Comment: Care, MongoDB recommends to not use this: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/built-in-roles/#__system